# How do I add significance circles to circular plot?

Tags: r, plot, significance

I made a circular plot in R:

```
vec <- c(90, 90, 100, 100, 120, 120, 120, 170, 290)
vec <- circular(vec, units = "degrees", rotatio = "clock")

plot(vec, units = "degrees", rotation = "clock", col = "lshkjf", zero = pi/2, shrink = 1.3)
points(vec, zero = pi/2, cex = 1.6, stack = TRUE, bins = 36, sep = 0.08)
arrows.circular(mean.circular(vec), rho.circular(vec), zero = pi/2, length = 0.2, col = "black", lwd = 3)
```

I would like to add inner dashed and outer line circles to indicate the length of the group’s mean vector needed for significance (p = 0.05 and p = 0.01, respectively), according to the Rayleigh test.

[This is what I have:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGFQX.png)

[This is what I would like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYiPB.png)